# request for a member "X" in something not a structure or a union

Tags: arduino-uno, i2c, mpu6050, ide

i was programming a Self Balancing    Robot, I am writing the code in vscode using platformio extension.

when i put the code i need to get the angle out of the gyro in another file (named angle.c) and including it in the main program, the ide throws with error, in every line I use the Wire library in the angle.c, however same code copy and paste it in the main program and it works.

P.S. the angle.c is just a file of functions and doesnot have any class.

Comment: Check the command when compiling angle.c. Is that that right compiler? Try the extension .cpp instead.

Comment: the compiler is checked, i'll try the .cpp extension

Comment: you can't include Wire.h in .c . Wire.h defines a class

Comment: that is it you are right, no please post it as an answer, so that i can accept it

Comment: the solution is to change the extension into .cpp because Wire.h defines classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A .c file is compiled with C compiler. If you include Wire.h which contains a class definition, the C compiler doesn't understand it and generates errors.

If your angle.c file doesn't have C code not compatible with C++, then change the extension of the file to .cpp and it will be compiled with C++ compiler.